pymqi: no way to deallocate message handles?
pymqi seems to leak memory when creating a pymqi.MessageHandle:
qm = pymqi.QueueManager(…)
for i in range(1000):
    x = pymqi.MessageHandle(qm)
    del x

memory use grows and grows. Furthermore it doesn't seem to expose the message handle deletion function in pymqe.c. Obviously it's possible for the most part to reuse the same handle, but AFAICT creating new ones periodically is inevitable (if one needs to reconnect, for instance). Is there some useful workaround for this that I'm not thinking of?

Looking in the PyMQI code there is no mention of the MQDLTMH verb anywhere so I think it simply has not been implemented. Suggest raising an issue on their GitHub project?

pymqi github is 100% locked down, you cannot create an issue or a pr, nor can you contact the maintainer at all, as far as I can tell. I tried informing the maintainer of an error in the documentation and had to resort to a DM on linkedin (he blocked me). great library love it

Fork it if you are unsatisfied with the current maintainer

Did you contact Zato? They seem to suggest that they are the ones who support it?
